setting log rolling policy zipkin image
With zipkin docker image, How to set rolling policy of zipkin'slogging.
i want to set zipkin's logging rolling policy.
with command or volume mounting for logback.xml, env
log didn't roll.
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration debug="true">
<appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
    <encoder>
        <pattern>[%thread] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n</pattern>
    </encoder>
</appender>

    <appender name="FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
        <encoder>
            <pattern>[%thread] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n</pattern>
        </encoder>
        <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
            <!-- Rollover every minute -->
                <fileNamePattern>/workspace/app.%d{yyyy-MM-dd_HH-mm-ss}.log</fileNamePattern>
            <!-- Keep logs for 60 minutes -->
            <maxHistory>60</maxHistory>
        </rollingPolicy>
    </appender>

    <root level="debug">
        <appender-ref ref="FILE" />
        <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
    </root>

</configuration>

here's my logback.xml. for test, I make it roll by seconds
